# How to read a value from inner node in firebase database?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have created a realtime database in firebase for an android application. The contents of data base are like

```
"Users" : {
    "fqwtFeCgp3fIvYay9PRppUyHv5C3" : {
      "email" : "ruthvikbr24@gmail.com",
      "post" : "manager",
      "name" : "eurhvik",
      "password" : "password",
      "phone" : "1234567890"
    }
}
```

Code :

```
database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(); 
String userId = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid(); 
userData = database.getReference("Users").child(userId); 
userData.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() { 
    @Override 
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) { 
        String post = dataSnapshot.child("gender").getValue(String.class); 
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),""+post,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```

Based on the value in `post` the functionalities will differ. When users sign up for the app through firebase Auth , one copy of it along with uid is stored in the database in the above format. how can i retrieve the value in `post` for a particular uid?

Comment: What have you tried so far in code?

Comment: I've tried adding a singleValueEventListener and in the onDataChange method I tried getting the gender value from the datasnapshot like dataSnapshot.child("Users").child(" "+mAuth.getCurrentUser.getUid()).child("gender").getValue()

Comment: Edit your post and add your implementation of `singleValueEventListener`

Comment: Show us what you have tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the post do the following:

```
String userId = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
DatabaseReference dbRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").child(userId);
dbRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
           String post = dataSnapshot.child("post").getValue(String.class);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

First add a reference to node `userId` then you can retrieve the `post` after attaching a listener.

Comment: your code won't work what are you're trying to run @Peter. `dbRef`.

Comment: I tried this but im getting this error                                                    
              'java.lang.String com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser.getUid()' on a null object reference

Comment: is your user login successfully ?

Comment: No it's not successful

Comment: @RuthvikB.R can you retrieve the email?

Comment: @RuthvikB.R Then please select as answer and provide upvote.